# Adding Layers on top of svg image

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, svg

I have an idea to create a map with Layers functionality.

I have initial image of map in svg format. I want to add Layers to it and each layer should have set of objects (coordinates of polygons). When I finish drawing polygons on eg. 1 Layer, I want to send coordinates of all objects to database and store them in Document(MongoDB), where I will have Name of Layer and array with objects coordinates. Then the idea is to turn on/off switch button which will add/remove Layers to initial map, fetch coordinates from database and put them on top of the map.

Is it possible to create such a functionality with svg?

My idea is that each Layer should have grouped polygons with `<g>` tag and each polygon should have unique class, so I will know what object it is. Is that correct approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! That should be possible with any modern javascript framework. I'd recommend one that uses JSX (like React), which makes working with dynamic svgs easier.

Here's some pseudo code for hiding layers:

```
function MapLayers() {
  return (
    <svg>
      {layerTwoIsOn && <g>/* layer 2 shapes here */</g>}
      {layerOneIsOn && <g>/* layer 1 shapes here */</g>}
    </svg>
  );
}
```